# Total number of some rows of a special record

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this:

```
SELECT * FROM `playerdetails` WHERE `power` + `violence` + `shooting` >= '50' LIMIT 1
```

I want the correct way.

Comment: Your query looks fine.  I would put the clauses on separate lines and `LIMIT` is not usually used without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Far from 'looking fine', this kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet. See normalisation. And a LIMIT clause without and ORDER BY clause is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `playerdetails` WHERE (`power` + `violence` + `shooting`) >= '50' LIMIT 1
```